# How to convert a task to a case....?

Tags: apex, trigger

We have one requirement,Client is asking to convert a task to a case.

How we can achieve this ,pls help in this regards..

Comment: A custom button or link on task tied to a Visualforce page is you best path forward.

Comment: I agree with @greenstork custom link or button and apex/visualforce depending if you need any additional interaction before the task is converted to a case. Moving in that direction if you let the SE community know what have you tried so far they can help guide you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods you can try, depending on your requirements.

If you are simply mapping field values from the Task to the new Case object and not adding or changing any additional information you could create a custom button on the Task to create the Case.  An example of this can be found [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gwhCAAQ).

If the user needs to customize the information being added to the Case, then you would want to add a custom button to the Task object that directs the User to a custom Visualforce page where they can customize and create the Case.

If this needs to happen automatically without the user's input, then you could use a Trigger to create the Case using the Task fields when certain conditions arise.

Comment: @user10060 Which one did you go with?  Also could you mark the answer as the one you chose?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Flow that, when a user clicks on a button on the task, a case is created. Here's a DreamForce [session video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8fNHGWxW2I) that will probably help.